# Perl Net::SSL occasionally throws error "read failed" when calling MS Azure Translation API

Tags: perl, azure, ssl, microsoft-translator

We have an automatic translation Perl script running on a client's server and we noticed that it would occasionally throw an error. The Script simply calls the Microsoft Azure Translation API to translate the data. (Replacing the deprecated Bing Translation API that was used before)

Net::SSL throws the following error:

```
Net::SSL::die_with_error(LWP::Protocol::https::Socket=GLOB(0x16aff1ec), "read failed")
```

The strange thing is that this error can't be reproduced, it seems that at some point, one of the calls doesn't return a value at all. (according to Net::SSL the error is thrown when the result of a HTTP request is undefined)

When I run the script just for the data that "caused" the error, it runs normally, so the input data does not seem to be the problem.

The script repeats the call 3 times in 10 second intervals before giving up, so a temporary connection problem seems unlikely as well.

Unfortunately I don't have direct access to the Azure account used and have to believe the partner who manages it, according to them it works normally and should.

I apologize that I can't give any more details. I just would like to know if anybody encountered a similar issue or has some experience with using the Azure Translation API.

Comment: It looks like you are forcing the use of outdated `Net::SSL`. There really isn't a good reason to do so. I am not sure which method you are using to do that, but don't.

Comment: That is, if you have  a `use Net::SSL` statement before `use LWP::UserAgent` or if you set `$Net::HTTPS::SSL_SOCKET_CLASS = 'Net::SSL'` or if you set `$ENV{PERL_NET_HTTPS_SSL_SOCKET_CLASS} = 'Net::SSL'` ... remove those.